# Sprite Kit Game Scene doesn't detect touches when HUDLayer added

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a sprite kit game where I have my game screen that checks for touches throughout the game. I just created a new class called HUDLayer which will contain everything from the user's score, lives, as well as the pause button. Once I added touch detection for my HUDLayer, i can now click on the pause button to pause the game and show the in-game menu, but now my game scene underneath it is no longer detecting any touches..how do I fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is how I added the HUDLayer to the GameScene

GameScene.m

```
-(void)setupHUDLayer
{
    HudLayer* _hudLayer = [[HudLayer alloc] initWithGameMode:@"survival"];
    [self addChild:_hudLayer];
}
```

Comment: Well, my guess is that `HudLayer` 'covers' the scene and therefore it receives the touches instead of the scene below it, try printing `HudLayer`'s dimensions to check if it isn't unnecessarily too big.

Comment: @AMI289 That is what is happening for sure. But I am sure there is a way to do this and only receive touches on the pause button within the HUD layer as opposed to receiving touches for the whole screen size

Comment: Sorry, wasn't focused and missed out the fact you basically pointed out what my comment says. Are there any objects that need to respond to touches directly below the `HudLayer`?

Comment: Set userInteractionEnabled = true only on the pause button node. It sounds as if you enabled user interaction for the entire layer. I don't think this property is inherited, so a parent can have it set to false with the child node still being able to receive touch events. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userInteractionEnabled

Comment: @AMI289 yes, like I said, my game scene is the parent of the HudLayer and the game scene has many "animal blocks" that need to respond to touches (flicks, drags, etc.)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D will try this out now. This is exactly what I did. Will let you know if it works

Comment: Yes, I've understand that, but I meant if any of those objects are directly below the `HudLayer`, meaning the `HudLayer` is transparent and have its own objects spread all over the screen (for example pause menu on top of screen, score on the bottom of the screen) or the `HudLayer` is just a black bar at the top, for example, in which case you could just reduce the frame size of it.

Comment: @AMI289 oh sorry. Yes, the score is the top left of the screen, the lives at the top right of the screen, and the pause button is at the bottom left of the screen. So essentially, the HUDLayer takes up the whole screen

Comment: @LearnCocos2D does setting it to false on the whole `HudLayer` will 'pass' the touches to the scene 'below' it?

Comment: I would give a try to LearnCocos2D's suggestion.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D your suggestion didn't work. Setting just the pause button node to userinteractionebaled = true still does not catch touches on the pause button

Comment: So before changing the `HudLayer`'s `userInteractionEnabled` property to false the pause button worked, but now it doesn't, even if the pause button itself is set to true?